# ajaxSuccess not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this short and simple code below but ajaxSuccess didn't get called. Any idea why?

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 async: true,
 url: "/userprofile",
 data: {
  'username': username
 },
        error: function (xhr, status, error){
        }
}); 

$().ajaxSuccess(function(event, request, settings) {
alert("OK");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 async: true,
 url: "/userprofile",
 data: {
  'username': username
 },
 success:function(res){
   alert(res);
 },
 error: function (xhr, status, error){
   /////
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

usually i will put the success inside the `.ajax()` call, but if you do it this way, it seems like you need to specify the selector as in the docs:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/